# Multipole Expansion of Point Charge at Origin

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage, multipole-expansion

The multipole expansion for the potential of some collection of point charges can be written as
$$
V=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\sum_{i}q_i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{r_i}{r})^nP_n(\cos\alpha)\,,
$$
where $r_i$ is the distance from the origin to charge $q_i$ and $P_n$ is the n-th Legendre polynomial. (I derived this expression as part of a homework problem and verified that it worked for some cases. If you see something wrong with it, let me know.) My question is, why is $V=0$ if we have a point charge at the origin? Why is not reproducing something like $\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}$? It seems unusual to me that shifting the charge a little bit up or down would produce a non-zero potential at some place very far from the charge.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ supposed to be?

Comment: Many common functions are recognized in MathJaX, so you can do `$\cos{\alpha}$` to get $\cos{\alpha}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, don't forget you also have an $n = 0$ term.

$(\frac{r_i}{r})^n = 0^0 = 1$ for $n = 0$, and thus $V = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0r}$ in that case.